# How are shopkeepers getting the MAC address of wifi enabled smartphones?

Tags: network, linux, wifi, mobile, mac-address

It is clear that some big malls are tracking all the wifi-enabled mobile phones before they are connected to the network... How can this be done?

I have a similar issue... how to get the MAC address of a mobile phone when it comes near my network but is not connected to it.

Answer (score 8):

Most WiFi enabled devices broadcast their Mac address when probing for networks to join in the vicinity.

By placing your own WiFi device in promiscuous/listening mode and utilizing a tool like Aircrack-ng, you can see and record all broadcast traffic enabling you to see if a device with a specific MAC address comes within earshot of your listening device.

See: [Is your smartphone broadcasting your movements when you shop?](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/10/25/is-your-smartphone-broadcasting-your-movements-when-you-shop/)

Comment: with this am able to see what are the wifi signals available in that range...but how can i know the mobile phones available in my wifi range

Comment: @spartan: See http://security.stackexchange.com/a/54068/884